# Remove Ubuntu 14.04 bootloader entry in Windows 8.1 Bootloader EFI Entry?

Tags: 14.04

Recently i installed ubuntu 14.04 on windows 8.1 pre-installed PC as Dual Boot. But due to some reasons i removed ubuntu 14.04 from my pc.Even though i removed ubuntu from my pc ubuntu entry in Windows EFI Bootloader remains. I tried deleting entry using Ubuntu live cd and EasyBCD software tool though it remains in EFI Bootloader entry.

Comment: Try to remove it using Boot option in "msconfig"

Comment: hey LiveWireBT, the process mentioned in that link won't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the ubuntu folder in the efi partition.

And in UEFI remove the ubuntu entry.

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

The "-v" option displays all the entries so you can confirm you're deleting the right one, and then you use the combination of "-b ####" (to specify the entry) and "-B" (to delete it).

Examples #5 is delete which is deleting the entry  4 or 0004.

```
efibootmgr -b 4 -B
```

http://linux.dell.com/cgi-bin/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=efibootmgr.git;a=blob_plain;f=README;hb=HEAD

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/efi-shells-and-scripting/

Launch EFI Shell from File System Device

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_Shell

Comment: I already mentioned in my question that i tried deleting the entry using ubuntu live cd in the same way as you mentioned using "efibootmgr"

Comment: Did you remove the ubuntu folder in the efi partition. Otherwise UEFI will keep adding a new entry as it adds all entries in efi folder.

Comment: It worked!!!I forget to delete the folder in efi partition.thanks oldfred